# ¿Cómo recorrer un string inversamente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, substr

Necesito extraer los últimas dos palabras separadas por espacios del string, ahorita las tomo recorriendo mi cadena de inicio a fin, necesito hacer de fin a inicio, este es mi código:

```
    var fullname = "Jose Ernesto Flores Camacho"
    var name =  fullname.substr(0,fullname.indexOf(' '))
    console.log(name)
```

Resultado: Jose

Necesito traer solo los apellidos.

Comment: ¿Y si el apellido es compuesto? Por ejemplo: "La Rosa" "De La Vega"

Comment: `fullname.split(" " )reverse().join(" ")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si solo quieres los apellidos podría servirte la función `split()`:

```js
  var fullname = "Jose Ernesto Flores Camacho"
  var array = fullname.split(" ");
  var apellidos = array[2]+" "+array[3];
  console.log(apellidos);
```

así lo conviertes en un array que puedes recorrer como gustes o en su defecto extraer las palabras que necesitas como te muestro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó..

Comment: en ES6, puedes hacer algo como `var [nombre, apellidop, apellidom] = fullname.split(" "); console.log(apellidop,apellidom);`

Comment: Esta no es usable, si en vez de dos nombres, solo tiene uno, ya no te funciona. Tienes que usar indices inversos.

Answer (score 2):

De esta forma puedes recorrer un array de desde el ultimo hacia el primer indice.

```
var string = "fasdfadfadfasdf fadsfasd adsfasdf";

for (var i = string.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(string[i]);
}
```

Ahora bien, depende de ti el criterio para los apellidos y puedes intentar otras formas como *regular expression.*